# How to decode base64-encoded inline attachments in email files saved from Thunderbird or Gmail?

Tags: shell, base64

Although `base64 [--decode]` works well when encoding and decoding files locally, I can't decode a base64-encoded inline attachment in an eml file saved from Thunderbird or Gmail.

I observed that base64-encoded blocks in all eml files are similar to what `base64` generates, but lines are of different length: the lines in base64-encoded blocks of text in eml files consist of **72 characters**, while the locally generated base64-encoded files consist of **76-character-long** lines. I suspect this discrepancy is why I cannot successfully use `base64 --decode` on snippets of eml files.

Is my hypothesis true? How can I decode these attachments?

Comment: They *should* be 76 characters long, according to RFC 4648. Anyway, it really doesn't matter: you should remove the line breaks before decoding them, anyways.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Strangely, the lines are 72 characters long in eml files, and I can get the inline attachment by removing all line breaks first, and then using the command `fold -w 76` to fix this. I'm now trying to write a shell script for this, if I can get the correct command to remove all line breaks - neither `tr -d '\n'` or `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'` worked. :-(

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I understand that the option `--wrap=COLS` is used while encoding (default=76), and apparently Thunderbird and Gmail eml files use column width 72 instead of 76. However, this option apparently is not meant to be used when decoding (it has no effect).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Sorry for the confusion. My problem is I can't decode eml files generated by Thunderbird or Gmail which come with 72 characters long lines. I was able to decode them only if I manually got rid of newlines, and created 76 characters long lines.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes! Finally got it! All I need was the command `dos2unix` before decoding apparently. It's unbelievable that both Thunderbird and my web browser saved those eml files with CRLF. Thank you very much.

Comment: OK, I did some research. It seems that from RFC733 through RFC822, [RFC2822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822) to RFC5322, CRLF is the right line ending for "Internet Message Format". Your eml files were saved in the format they should be.

Comment: Thanks. IMHO then the command `base64 --decode` should have detected this, and should have been able to decode regardless of the newline character type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `base64` performs *encoding* by wrapping text at default column width of 76 characters, unless another value is specified with the option `--wrap=COLS`.

The command `base64 --decode` is expected to work regardless of column width, e.g. the text block might consist of a single line (it doesn't matter how long), or multiple lines wrapped at any fixed column width.

The problem with "Internet Message Format" (*.eml) files saved from Thunderbird or a web mail like GMail actually is that they use DOS/Windows ("CRLF" / "\r\n") - and not Unix/Linux ("LF" / "\n") - line endings, while both `base64` and `base64 --decode` use the latter.

This means, "Internet Message Format" (*.eml) files (or base64-encoded text blocks retrieved from them) should first be converted using the `dos2unix` command *before* executing the `base64 --decode` command.